# Stop paying Jira account

Tags: backup, jira, backlog

What if I stop paying Jira, would I lose whole my backlog and other achievements of my team or it just would be frozen?

And is there any way to backup all the data of account in the Jira?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find backup instructions here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/cancelations-744721616.html

I believe you will lose access but the data will still exist for 2 weeks, so you can reactivate:

"Once your site has been deactivated (i.e. your site has been taken offline), you have two weeks to pay your outstanding quote or contact Atlassian to have the site restored before your data will be permanently deleted. Note that data backups for permanently deleted instances can sometimes be retrieved by raising a ticket with our Support team within the first month after your instance has been deleted." - https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/billing-and-user-count-744721614.html